# Почему не работает переключение checked для input[type=radio]?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]

Есть две кнопки с чекбоксами внутри. 
Вот разметка.

```html
<label class="cloud-script-card">
  <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>My Script №1</span>
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <input type="radio">
    <label></label>
  </div>
</label>

<label class="cloud-script-card">
  <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>My Script №2</span>
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <input type="radio">
    <label></label>
  </div>
</label>
```

пытаюсь сделать переключение по клику (по умолчанию обе кнопки белого цвета, при нажатии кнопка синеет и появляется галка).
есть проблема - при клике на другую кнопку никак не удаётся снять с input псевдокласс :checked

дошёл до следующего JS-кода

```js
$(".cloud-script-card").on("click", function(){
  $(".cloud-script-card").removeClass('active-script-card');
  $('.checkbox input:checked').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).addClass('active-script-card');
});
```

подскажите, как добавить :checked кнопке, которая нас интересует

Comment: Задайте input'ам одинаковые имена. name="test"

Comment: спасибо огромное, решение было на поверхности!

Answer (score 5):

Добавьте радио-кнопкам имена, чтобы создать группу.

```html
<label class="cloud-script-card">
<i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>My Script №1</span>
<div class="ui checkbox">
<input type="radio" name="script">
<label></label>
</div>
</label>

<label class="cloud-script-card">
<i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>My Script №2</span>
<div class="ui checkbox">
<input type="radio" name="script">
<label></label>
</div>
</label>
```